# Images are loading in Table View in simulator but not in Device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm parsing images from JSON data and displaying in Table View. My code to display images in table view is -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellidentifier=@"MyCell";
OnlineCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
cell = [[OnlineCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
}

cell.userLabel.text = [self.allusername objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
imageURL    = [self.alluserphoto objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


  cell.userIMage.image = img;
  [indicator stopAnimating];
 });
 });
return cell;
}
```

## Simulator Output -

[image]

## Device OutPut -

**Please tell me the how could i get images in device.**

[image]

Comment: What kind of URL do you use ? Give us an example...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès  http://static.vconnect.co/img/profile-photo.jpg .. image does not get load from this source in device but loading in simulator

Comment: Are images not loaded even when you wait a little bit and scroll the tableview ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès no i waited long still images r not loading

Comment: From your screenshots, it seems that the problem appears only with THIS image, right ?

Comment: yes this image is coming from this url http://static.vconnect.co/img/profile-photo.jpg  which is opening in simulator..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66552/discussion-between-imran-and-jean-baptiste-yunes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i can see two screenshot one is Simulator and one is Device that two image common Load at both end simulator and device. So i think issue in to you image that comes from web side. Because you code is correct if there is issue in code then that not load two image as well in device.

Please test with change the image with First loaded image from your back End side and check once that have to load. put first loaded image for all response instead of goggles image that not load in device. i am dame sure issue is in image not in code.

Answer (score 1):

**Debugging Suggestion 1:** On the device, make sure that the image is accessible. You can try opening the image in Safari. If safari is opening the image, it means that image is accessible.

**Debugging Suggestion 2:** If the image is accessible, try loading the image synchronously and debug if you're getting the required data (on the device):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.photoImagePath]; // Is URL valid?
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; // Is data nil?
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]; // Is image nil?
```

Then, try loading the image asynchronously, like this:

```
__weak UIImageView *weakImgageView = cell.userIMage;
imageURL = [self.alluserphoto objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        weakImgageView.image = image;
        [indicator stopAnimating];
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir, it would be much simplier if u update ur working answer like my code. i m getting values in debug and safari is also loading images..

Comment: path and image are not nill

Comment: i m getting image at row 1.. remaining rows are blank in table view

Comment: And other content in the cell is being populated e.g. title?

Comment: yes other things are populating except image in all rows

Comment: i tried with SDWebImage but setImageWithURL is not coming in [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString ......] here

Answer (score 0):

The default image is not coming properly. This is what I suspect. Please check if you are giving the name properly or not. This could be the issue.

Comment: names are correct and url also right. how does it work fine in simulator

Answer (score -1):

Set default image until you fetch image asynchronously from `JSON`.

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
```

When you fetch image in asynchronously method means it will fetch depend on image size & internet speed. So you just keep a default image until it fetch completely from server

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    OnlineCell *cell = (OnlineCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSArray *nib = nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomCellNibName" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    // Your code


    cell.userLabel.text = [self.allusername objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            //NSData *imagedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.alluserphoto objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
            NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.alluserphoto objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                                       NSData * data,
                                                       NSError * error) {
                                       if (!error){
                                           UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                           // do whatever you want with image
                                           if (image) {
                                               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                   OnlineCell *updateCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                                                   if (updateCell)
                                                       cell.userIMage.image = image;
                                               });
                                           }
                                       }

                                   }];

        });
}
```

Comment: Wait i will suggest one more option

Comment: Change kBgQueue into dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

Comment: which cell u r returning in ur code bro...ang getting crash if i use updatedCell as return...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66544/discussion-between-imran-and-svmrajesh).

Comment: Declare your custom cell as like follows 'OnlineCell *cell = (OnlineCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];' instead of 'OnlineCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];'

Comment: See how am declared in your code which am updated newly